# Why do accordion panels not allow onClick Sound action to be performed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently trying to make a slideshow play a sound when you click the next, prev buttons which is contained within an accordion tag. The sound clip works on slideshows which are not within an accordion and im not sure why it does this as it should not affect anything by being in there. How do i go about fixing this?

Html code:

```
<button class="accordion">Images</button>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="slideshow-container">
            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <img src=" style="width:450px; height:300px">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <img src="" style="width:450px; height:300px">
            </div>

            <a class="prev" onClick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onClick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
                          <audio id="click">
                <source src="click.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
             </audio>
        </div>
    </div>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].onclick = function(){
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
            }
        }
    </script>

<script>
         var slideIndex = 1;
            showSlides(slideIndex);

           var audioElem = document.getElementById("click");

            function playSound() {
             audioElem.currentTime = 0;
             audioElem.play();
            }

           function plusSlides(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex += n);
          playSound();
           }

          function currentSlide(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex = n);
          playSound();
          }


    function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    }
</script>
```